# Synapse production deployment errors

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to deploy my synapse pipelines and notebooks to production.It's working fine on non-produciton environment. I added followed ansible role parameters.

---

azure_synapse_linkedservice_parameter_override:
- name: Environment
value: "{{ cvx_environment_name }}"

```
azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace: true
azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace_dict:
  dev:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalakedev
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-t323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  

  test:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalaketest
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-t323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  
  prod:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalake
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-p323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  
azure_synapse_deploy_start_triggers: true
azure_synapse_deploy_user_pipelines:
  - P3 Data move from RAW to REFINED
  - gomwp_produce_well_productivity
  - gomwp_produce_pi_af
```

---

Followed is the error.
2023-05-31T14:41:47.8997088Z fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace_dict[azure_synapse_deploy_environment_name] | dict2items }}): dict2items requires a dictionary, got <class 'NoneType'> instead."}

---

Please help me what am I doing wrong.

azure_synapse_linkedservice_parameter_override:
- name: Environment
value: "{{ cvx_environment_name }}"

```
azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace: true
azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace_dict:
  dev:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalakedev
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-t323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  

  test:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalaketest
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-t323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  
  prod:
  ls_chevrondatalake: chevrondatalake
  ls_keyvault: https://gomwp-p323-cvx.vault.azure.net
  
azure_synapse_deploy_start_triggers: true
azure_synapse_deploy_user_pipelines:
  - P3 Data move from RAW to REFINED
  - gomwp_produce_well_productivity
  - gomwp_produce_pi_af
```